# CSS media queries for PHP blocks in a split window

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, media-queries

Good morning everyone,

In a WordPress environment, I am trying to create a **split window with responsive PHP blocks** on each side.

I am looking for a solution to adapt the css media queries to the width of the split screen instead of the width of the full screen.
The main problem is that it is **not possible to modify the css queries** that have the following format:

```css
  @media (max-width: 992px) {}
```

There is a functional solution with iframes, the problem is that in a WordPress environment, I have to load all wordpress for all iframes (2 or 3 times) which is a loss of performance.

The same problem appears with the HTML `<embed>` tag.

My question is: Do you think there is a way for `<iframe>` children to access WordPress PHP functions from the parent window (and avoid to load the WordPress environment in the iframe)? Or maybe a better way than iframes to handle media requests in a split window?

I may not have the right approach for this problem, an outside look would certainly open me to new possibilities.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you actually measured the performance impact of this? Although WordPress has “weight”, with proper tuning and utilizing themes and plugins written with an awareness of performance it really shouldn’t matter that much, unless you have very non-performant hosting, or have many users.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your feedback. I didn't measure the impact on performance but it was not suitable for my project (potential use of a large number of iframes).

However, I was able to find a very interesting solution by using the ***shadow DOM***.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to find a very interesting solution by using the ***shadow DOM***.